# Are there any theoretic or computational criteria to apply log transformation on a sample dataset?

Tags: data-visualization, logarithm, scales

I am developing an R shiny app that contains more than 1,000 variables as choices for the user. It plots a choropleth map and an histogram. However for many of those, the visual information is helpless since data are extremely skewed. I tried to find criteria to apply log scale automatically when it is appropriate, but couldn't find any.

I tried to used 'G1' skewness coefficient but it is not consistent to all cases (for many of them, log scale will not be beneficial).
Does anyone know consolidated scientific criteria for log transformation?

Comment: This is quite hard to solve in general, but automation would need to start with a check that all values are positive. There are many skewed positive variables where the original scale will work just fine. Sure, only small portions of the map will be in the highest categories, but that is almost always true for topography too.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, indeed, all values are positive for all variables. If any is negative, it is a wrong input that must be unconsidered.

Comment: Much depends on your ambitions. It sounds as if you want to write a detailed app that applies only to certain kinds of data.  Good luck with that, but I can only confirm that it will be harder to do well than you hoped.